# Can someone explain interference alignment in layman terms

Tags: wireless

I am reading about current research going in wireless communications. I came across the term  **interference alignment** for MIMO systems.

Can someone explain what is interference alignment?

Comment: Tons of papers are coming up when google "interference alignment". Including some freely available tutorials.

Comment: Imagine you are in a room holding a conversation with someone (a sender-receiver pair), you can clearly hear what each other has to say. Now twenty more people enter the same room and start up their conversations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interference channel is where several sender-receiver pairs share a common media so that transmission of information from one sender to its corresponding receiver interferes with communications between the other pair

summary from this article [A Tutorial on Interference Alignment](https://www3.nd.edu/~jnl/ee80653/tutorials/farzad.pdf)